# How to force :fullscreen pseudoclass to follow the same rules as :not(:fullscreen)?

Tags: javascript, css

I am changing the background-color dynamically, and I need the same thing to happen in fullscreen as well. Unfortunately pseudoclasses styles cannot be modified straight from javascript.

Is there any way in which I can say that the :fullscreen class should follow the same rules as :not(:fullscreen)

Any method to change :fullscreen styling from javascript dynamically (without having any css and changing the class of the element), would also be appreciated.

I would prefer a no-jquery solution, but if it has to be jquery, then it has to.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54749402/8620333

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for this. (Not [supported by MSIE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)).

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", event => {
    const t = event.target;
    if (t.dataset && t.dataset.color) {
        document.body.style.setProperty("--my-color", t.dataset.color);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    --my-color: yellow;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    background: var(--my-color);
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>

<button type="button" data-color="red">Red</button>
<button type="button" data-color="blue">Blue</button>
```

---

You could also [directly modify the CSS rulesets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409225/changing-a-css-rule-set-from-javascript).

---

However, if `:fullscreen {}` and `:not(:fullscreen) {}` have identical rules, then you might as well just use `* {}`