# Workaround for animation of background-position on pseudo selector in progress element

Tags: html, css

I have an indeterminate progress bar:

```
<progress max="100"></progress>
```

I've styled it with a green background with 45-degree stripes:

```
progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
}

progress:not([value])::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 66%, transparent 66%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(#b3ee3a, #b3ee3a);
  background-size: 2.5em 1.25em, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-position: 10%;
  animation-name: stripes;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes stripes {
  from {background-position: 0%}
  to {background-position: 100%}
}
```

(Full Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/w9x7sm6c/4/)

Unfortunately, the animation doesn't work.  The issue seems to stem from a Chrome bug/feature:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=486195

> Closing this as WontFix.
>
> Reason: @keyframes rule name is scoped, so the name specified is only available
>   in the same treescope (i.e. in the same document or shadow root).
>   progress::-webkit-progress-value pierces document-UA shadow root boundary
>   and styles the element, but animation name defined in the document treescope
>   isn't available in UA shadow root, thus the animation doesn't apply.
>
> ...
>
> A workaround could be to make your own widget and animate it, which should
>   work all (if CSS animation is implemented) browsers.

It seems to me that the suggested workaround is to just not use `<progress>`, which seems like bad advice to me.  I'd rather use the correct semantic elements than inventing something that does the same thing.

Is there any workaround I can use for animating this progress bar in its indeterminate state?

Comment: some JS to simulate the animation maybe?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, I was just trying that out!  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to select `progress:not([value])::-webkit-progress-bar` in JavaScript.  `document.querySelector()` for it returns `null`.

Comment: yes you will need CSS variable (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54749459/8620333)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider the common pseudo element to create this.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

progress {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  position:relative;
}

progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 0.3em;  
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  box-shadow: 0 0.3em 0.3em rgba(0,0,0, 0.3) inset;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  background-color: #b3ee3a;
}


progress:not([value])::-webkit-progress-bar {
  /* nothing here*/
}
progress:not([value])::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius: 0.3em; 
  background:
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 66%, transparent 66%) left/2.5em 1.25em,
    #b3ee3a;
  background-position: 10%;
  animation-name: stripes;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes stripes {
  from {background-position: 0%}
  to {background-position: 100%}
}
```

```html
<progress max="100" value="33"></progress>
<progress max="100" value="50"></progress>
<progress max="100" value="90"></progress>
<progress max="100"></progress>
```

Or use JS to update the values using CSS variables combined with timeout.

Here is a basic example to show the value change:

```js
function update() {
  document.querySelector('progress:not([value])').style.setProperty("--c", "100%");
}
```

```css
progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
}

progress:not([value])::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background:
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 66%, transparent 66%),
    #b3ee3a;
  background-size: 2.5em 1.25em;
  background-position: var(--c,10%);
  transition:1s all;
}
```

```html
<progress max="100"></progress>

<button onClick="update()">change</button>
```