# how to change the color of "progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value" property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change the color of

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
                background-color: #00bdf8;
            }
```

at different values selected by the user
when user select 30% then color should be red, at 60% it will be Yellow and then green

```
<input type="range" max="100" step="1" class="inputseekbar" id="range">
 <progress max="100" id="progressbarcolor"></progress>
 <output for="range" class="output"></output>
```

what will be the JS or Jquery[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j9fJ.png)

`<output>` tag is used for showing the "%".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use CSS variable and adjust the value using JS depending on the value of the progress.

Here is a basic example:

```js
var progress = document.querySelectorAll("progress");
for(var i = 0;i<progress.length;i++) {
   var n = 2 * parseInt(progress[i].getAttribute("value"));
   progress[i].style.setProperty("--c", "rgb("+n+","+n+",20)");
}
```

```css
progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background:grey;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {  
  background-color: var(--c,red);
}
```

```html
<progress max="100"  value="20"></progress>
<progress max="100"  value="50"></progress>
<progress max="100"  value="60"></progress>
<progress max="100"  value="100"></progress>
```

You can also easily do it on change:

```js
var progress = document.querySelector("progress");

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
   progress.setAttribute('value',this.value);
   progress.style.setProperty("--c", "rgb("+2*this.value+","+2*this.value+",20)");
});
```

```css
progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background:grey;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {  
  background-color: var(--c,red);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" max="100" step="1" class="inputseekbar" id="range">
<progress max="100"  value="50"></progress>
```

---

Related:

[How to update placeholder color using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54749402/8620333)

[Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333)

Answer (score -1):

Please Check For 30% value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>


progress {
  color: red;
  background: green
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: red;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: green;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="range" max="100" step="1" class="inputseekbar" id="range">
 <progress max="100" value="30" id="progressbarcolor"></progress>
 <output for="range" class="output"></output>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My question is different. You have defined hard-coded value in HTML progress tag. But i want when user drag that progress bar to 30% then the color should be change.