# How do I change ::selected in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I change `::selected` in the whole page in JavaScript?
Like changing this in Javascript:

```css
::selected {
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: First step would be to define what `::selected` should do/match

Comment: Do you mean `::selection`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749402/how-to-update-placeholder-color-using-javascript