# Use pseodoelements in JS

Tags: javascript, animation, pseudo-element

I want to handle pseudoelement ::after or ::before and  animate that in JavaScript. I try to use querySelector like this

```
const element = doument.querySelector(".example::after")
```

but it return null. How can I use pseudoelement in JS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get pseudo element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872290/how-to-get-pseudo-element)

Comment: Depending on what you're going to do with the pseudo-element, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54749459/1169519) probably the best way to access pseudo-elements in JS.

Comment: @Ivar I saw that but in this method I can get css style but I need to set style